# How to add a character into a chararray that already have character in ipython 3

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter

In python 2.7 I can do...

```
>>> import numpy
>>> flag=numpy.chararray(10) + '     '
>>> flag
chararray(['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
  dtype='|S6')
>>> flag[5] = 'a'
>>> flag
chararray(['', '', '', '', '', 'a', '', '', '', ''],
    dtype='|S6')
>>> flag[5]=flag[5]+'b'
>>> flag
chararray(['', '', '', '', '', 'ab', '', '', '', ''],
    dtype='|S6')
```

But this did not word in python 3.....
BTW. How can I save the "flag" array with some number array in to a text file. Like

1 1

1 1

1 1

1 1

1 1

1 1 ab

1 1

1 1

1 1

1 1

I had used 
np.savetxt but.... won't work....

many thx.....

Comment: in python 3 `chararray` uses bytes objects instead of `str`s so just add a `b` prefix to all the associated strings and it will work.

Comment: This time I got...
    TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly